# Сгруппировать данные по неделям

Tags: postgresql

Просьба подсказать советом. Есть задача которую я не могу быстро решить. Нужно из базы вывести записи и сгруппировать по неделям, результат должен быть такой:

```
Неделя:        Count       price
01.01.2018     658754        100   
07.01.2018     5464654       200
14.01.2018     54645         300
21.01.2018     465465456     350
```

Мой запрос:

```
SELECT  count(rs.name) AS count_tariff, (count(rs.name) * sum(rs.price)) AS value, rs.downdate
FROM rbt_bd rs
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND rs.downdate >= '2017-08-28'
  AND rs.downdate <= '2018-08-28'
GROUP BY date_part('week', rs.downdate::date)
OFFSET 0
LIMIT 20
```

Но он не работает, т.к требуется добавить rs.downdate в group by, тогда я получу не тот результат который мне нужен. Как на pgsql получить требуемый мне результат, это возможно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Функция `date_part`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) вернёт только сам номер недели. То есть результат неверный уже для указанных в запросе дат: и `2017-08-28` и `2018-08-28` относятся к 35 недели и будут сгруппированы в одну строку результата. Что очевидно не то что нужно. Необходимо к группировке добавить ещё номер года и выбирать эти самые данные вместо исходного `rs.downdate`.

Впрочем, заметно удобнее будет воспользоваться функцией `date_trunc`, которая усекает дату до указанной отметки и возвращает первую дату этой отметки. Запрос получится:

```
SELECT  date_trunc('week', rs.downdate), count(rs.name) AS count_tariff, (count(rs.name) * sum(rs.price)) AS value
FROM rbt_bd rs
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND rs.downdate >= '2017-08-28'
  AND rs.downdate <= '2018-08-28'
GROUP BY date_trunc('week', rs.downdate)
```

Можно и сразу [переформатировать дату](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT  to_char(date_trunc('week', rs.downdate), 'DD.MM.YYYY'), count(rs.name) AS count_tariff, (count(rs.name) * sum(rs.price)) AS value
FROM rbt_bd rs
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND rs.downdate >= '2017-08-28'
  AND rs.downdate <= '2018-08-28'
GROUP BY date_trunc('week', rs.downdate)
```

---

Отдельно хочу заметить, что `limit` и, тем более, `offset` не имеют смысла без `order by`. СУБД имеет полное право выдавать любые не сортированные данные на своё усмотрение.